# Lifetime of connected app record / tokens

Tags: oauth, developer-edition

With the recently announced plan to de-activate (and presumably at some point delete) inactive developer edition orgs, I've been wondering what's the lifetime of a connected app record created in a DE org? say i have a DE Org, and create a connected app, and ship a native app that uses the client secret for the connected app, everything's fine so far.

If my DE org is de-activated, what happens to my app, does it still work (in particular do OAuth logins still work)? if the DE org goes from de-activated to deleted, does my app still work then? (obviously not in that org!). If i forget to login to my DE org every 6 months, are users of my native apps going to be screwed ?

Comment: Would usage of the Connected App in the last 6 months be enough to prevent the DE org going into the deactivated/locked state?

Comment: I don't think so if its not used to login to the org that it was created in.